# What happens to a Curse when the Enchanted Player dies?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

This question is regarding the 'Curse' Auras from Innistrad block, such as [Curse of Exhaustion](http://magiccards.info/dka/en/5.html). When the player enchanted by the Curse dies, what happens to the Curse. Does it remain in play with no actual target or effect?

Comment: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/4749/3128

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Aura is put into your graveyard due to 303.4b.

> 303.4b If an Aura is enchanting an illegal object or player, the object it was attached to no longer exists, or **the player it was
> attached to has left the game**, the Aura is put into its owner’s
> graveyard.

Also, if you had two [Curse of Exhaustion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Curse%20of%20Exhaustion) in play enchanting two players that somehow died simultaneously, both Auras would be put into the graveyard simultaneously, due to this rule:

> 704.3. Whenever a player would get priority [...], the game checks for any of the listed conditions for state-based actions, then performs all applicable state-based actions simultaneously as a single event. [...]