# Will Exquisite Blood trigger even if the life loss eliminates the player

Tags: magic-the-gathering

We are trying to workout a ruling for a multi player game of mtg involving 8 players and a 1 player with an [Exquisite Blood](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Exquisite%20Blood).

So lets say there are eight players. Player **#3** has Exquisite Blood. Player **#5** hits player **#8** for 100 damage. Player **#8** dies and Exquisite Blood triggers (For 100).

The confusion comes in for when Exquisite Blood resolves. As the opponent that lost 100 life not longer exists, will Exquisite Blood still resolve?

Comment: I edited your question a bit to collapse the list. I'm confused though: player #3 is the one with exquisite blood, and nothing happened to them. Did you mean to suggest player #8 has exquisite blood?

Comment: Player #3 has the Exquisite Blood. Nothing happens to them. The confusion is; does player #3 gain all 100 life or the fact that the opponent that lost the life is dead at the time the spell resolve make any difference.

Comment: Oh, right, yeah, this makes sense now.

Comment: Fixed the title a bit. It's still misleading because the EB triggers when the life loss happens, which is before the player is eliminated by the SBAs.

Comment: Related: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/4749/in-mtg-what-happens-when-a-player-loses-in-multiplayer (which is kind of a more general version of this question)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Player #3 will gain 100 life.**

The fact that #8 is no longer in the game has no effect on Exquisite Blood's triggered ability. All of its effect was put on the stack when #8 lost 100 life. It does not require #8 to be in play when it resolves, because it does not check for any current information about that player. Even if it did, rule 800.4g would take effect:

*If an effect requires information about a specific player, the effect uses the current information about that player if he or she is still in the game; otherwise, the effect uses the last known information about that player before he or she left the game.*

Only effects that require a target are affected if that target is no longer legal or does not exist anymore; they would be countered in that case.

Comment: interesting side question, although not  really appropriate for this format - is player #8 a terrible person if he scoops before damage is dealt to prevent the life gain?

Comment: I can only confirm that conceding would prevent the damage and therefore the trigger. It doubt it would be unsporting conduct either even in a multiplayer match where his decision would influence the rest of the game, because every player may concede at any time, immediately removing him from the game. Whether or not that makes him a "terrible" person is indeed beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Maybe not the best place for this, yet still related, would conceding stop a Exquisite Blood + Sanguine Bond from killing all players?

Comment: As I wrote, conceding before the life loss happens prevents Exquisite Blood from triggering, and therefore Sanguine Blood as well.