# Does an enchantment curse go to grave if the cursed player loses?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

In a multiplayer game, I enchanted someone else with Fraying Sanity. They milled out. Does [Fraying Sanity](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFraying%20Sanity%5d) go to the graveyard when that player loses, or does it still stay attached?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Fraying Sanity](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFraying%20Sanity%5d) is put into your graveyard when the player enchanted with it loses and leaves the game. From the [Comprehensive rules](http://media.wizards.com/2017/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020170825.txt):

> 303.4c If an Aura is enchanting an illegal object or player as defined by its enchant ability and other applicable effects, the object it was attached to no longer exists, or the player it was attached to has left the game, the Aura is put into its owner’s graveyard. (This is a state-based action. See rule 704.)