# Etali and returning casted cards questions

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

With our EDH group we can't completely figure out what happens in the following cases:

After attacking with [Etali, Primal Storm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEtali%2c%20Primal%20Storm%5d) and casting some of the exiled cards, some of them for example creatures, are now on the board for player John. John is the one playing Etali.

Let's say one of the creatures was originally in Ben's deck. That creature gets killed. Does this creature go back to Ben's graveyard? Or does the card go back to exile?

Comment: #2 is; and should just be edited out of the question. #1 is a good non-duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to Q1 is: **The creature goes to it's owner's (in your case, Ben's) graveyard.**

This is supported by CR701.7a:

> 701.7. Destroy
>
> > 701.7a To destroy a permanent, move it from the battlefield to its owner’s graveyard.

Q2 already has an answer [here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/4749/in-mtg-what-happens-when-a-player-loses-in-multiplayer).

Answer (score 3):

**When a creature dies, it goes into the owner's graveyard.**

> 701.7a To destroy a permanent, move it from the battlefield to its owner’s graveyard.
>
> 704.5h If a creature has toughness greater than 0, and it’s been dealt damage by a source with deathtouch since the last time state-based actions were checked, that creature is destroyed. Regeneration can replace this event.

There are certain effects that could override this default, such as [Rest in Peace](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRest%20in%20Peace%5d). But [Etali, Primal Storm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEtali%2c%20Primal%20Storm%5d) doesn't have any ability that changes what happens when a creature dies, so it will go into Ben's graveyard like normal.